# MySQL Select Statement Create Column Then Compare

Tags: mysql, sql

Very New to SQL. Trying to get the results to show only when TotalSales is Less Than the goal.

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.Column1) AS TotalSales
FROM Table 1
WHERE Table1.Goal > TotalSales
GROUP BY EmployeeID;
```

It is giving me error 1054: Unknown column.

Again, very basic but I'm stuck. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sound like a not normalized table to me. From your query I guess there should be one goal for each sales person. Yet there seems to be an instance of goal in every row of the table apparently tracking the activity of the sales people. Consider reviewing your database design.

Answer (score -1):

You need `subquery` with `JOIN` :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.TotalSales
FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN (
       SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(Table1.Column1) AS TotalSales
       FROM Table1
       GROUP BY EmployeeID ) t2
ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID 
WHERE t1.Goal > t2.TotalSales;
```

Comment: Great, but you couldn't know that from the information provided.